# Ошибка при запуске службы бота телеграмм - no Module Named "telebot"

Tags: ubuntu, telebot

Хочу развернуть бота на сервере ubuntu 20.04
При запуске напрямую командой python3 main.py отрабатывает нормально и бот начинает работать, но такой вариант не подходит потому что при закрытии ssh подключения бот отключается

Взял простенький вариант службы -

```
[Unit]
Description=GGent - Telegram Bot
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/tgbot/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/tgbot/main.py
RestartSec=60
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Служба работает все отлично, но бот - нет в журнале такая ошибка:

```
Started GGEnt - Telegram Bot.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/tgbot/main.py", line 1, in <module>
     import requests, json, time, datetime, telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
tgbot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
: tgbot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

no Module Named "telebot"

```
Package                Version
---------------------- -----------
certifi                2019.11.28
chardet                3.0.4
command-not-found      0.3
dbus-python            1.2.16
distro                 1.4.0
distro-info            0.23ubuntu1
idna                   2.8
language-selector      0.1
netifaces              0.10.4
pip                    20.0.2
PyGObject              3.36.0
pymacaroons            0.13.0
PyNaCl                 1.3.0
pyTelegramBotAPI       4.10.0
python-apt             2.0.1
PyYAML                 5.3.1
requests               2.22.0
requests-unixsocket    0.2.0
setuptools             45.2.0
six                    1.14.0
ssh-import-id          5.10
telebot-calendar       1.2
ubuntu-advantage-tools 8001
ufw                    0.36
unattended-upgrades    0.1
urllib3                1.25.8
wheel                  0.34.2
```

pip list такой, telebot там нет, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. `tgbot` ≠ `ramziv_bot`

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: `При запуске напрямую командой python3 main.py отрабатывает нормально` — но вы же запускаете совершенно иную команду, что-то вроде: `$ sudo -u root env -i sh -c 'cd /home/tgbot/ && /usr/bin/python3 /home/tgbot/main.py'`

Comment: и как поправить запуск службы?

Comment: найдите разницу и попробуйте её нивелировать. ну или воспользуйтесь gnu/screen или tmux.

Answer (score 0):

решилось `sudo pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI`